# Intuition for definition of Gromov norm?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. A $k$-chain in the singular chain complex of $X$ is a linear combination $c = \sum_1^k a_i\sigma_i$, where $\sigma_i$ are continuous maps from the standard $k$-simplex $\Delta^k$ to $X$. Thus we can natually define the norm of the cycle to be$$\|c\| = \sum_1^k |a_i|.$$

For $\alpha \in H_k(X, \mathbb{R})$, the Gromov norm of $\alpha$ is defined to be$$\|\alpha\| = \inf\{\|c\| : c \text{ is a singular cycle which represents }\alpha\}.$$What is the intuition behind the definition of the Gromov norm?

Comment: It measures how complicated the cycle is needed to represent the homology class.

Comment: You could do worse than study this for the fundamental classes of surfaces. I'd never encountered it, but I would guess the Gromov norm grows for fundamental classes of higher genus surfaces.

Comment: You probably get bounds in terms of the euler characteristic and such

Comment: For closed oriented surfaces $S$ of genus $p\ge 2$, $||S||=c(2p-2)$, where $c$ is some universal constant, I forgot which one. Did you try the book by Benedetti and Petronio? They discuss Gromov norm in great detail.

Comment: The original lecture notes of William Thurston, "The Geometry and Topology of 3-manifolds", contains the original description of the Gromov norm, and it remains very accessible. http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/

Answer (score 2):

Part of the intuition is that if you fix the dimension $n$ and consider the set of all closed hyperbolic $n$-manifolds $X$, the Gromov norm is proportional to the volume of $X$. The proportionality constant turns out to be equal to the maximal volume of an ideal simplex in $\mathbb{H}^n$ (or the supremal volume of a finite simplex). This tells us, intuitively, that the way to acheive the infimum in the definition of $||c||$ is to choose a chain whose singular simplices lift to the universal cover $\mathbb{H}^n$ so as to be close to ideal simplices (when lifted to the universal cover).